# Проблема с FORM авторизацией в singlepage приложении через j_security_check

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, авторизация

Проблема следующая:
1. Пользователь авторизуется через j_security_check
2. Накатывается новое приложение на сервер
3. Пользователь становится неавторизованным
4. Пользователь делает запрос, его перенаправляют на страницу авторизации
5. Пользователь авторизуется с 302 и выполняется запрос на шаге 4, так как j_security_check добавляет в заголовок Location

НО. Мне не нужно его выполнять, у меня должно загрузится основное окно, так как весь клиент написан на JS с одной страницей index.html.

Как сделать так, чтоб j_security_check не отправлял предыдущий запрос?

Comment: Такой способ авторизации не годится для мобильных приложений.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но у меня не мобильное приложение

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось таким:
1. Выносим сервлет выхода из защищенных ресурсов
2. Мапим

```
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/auth</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/auth</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
```

на один сервлет, который возвращает 401 и чистит куки.

В итоге:
1. Пользователь авторизуется через j_security_check
2. Накатывается новое приложение на сервер
3. Пользователь становится неавторизованным
4. Пользователь делает запрос, его перенаправляют на сервлет auth, тот чистит куки
5. Обновляется страница на страницу с логином
6. Пользователь вводит данные и попадает на основную панель работы